# Append Divs next to each other and center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, css-float

I am appending multiple divs to another div. I want to append 3 divs in a row and then go keep appending below that. Is there anyway to do that?

Right now with my code:

```
$('#append_div').append(`<div class="w-100" style="display:inline-block; float: left;"></div>`);
    $('#append_div').append(`<div class="col-4 dynamic-chart"><h6 class="chartName">${Name}</h6><div id=${chart_id}></div></div>`)
```

My div look like:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
...
...
...
```

Inside the div `chart_id`, I have highcharts. I want them to float next to each other as below but instead they are all appending one under the other.

I want my appended divs to look like this:

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
....
```

Is there a way to append in this format?

Comment: Line breaks in HTML between elements mean nothing, so your two HTML excerpts are identical in real terms. If you want `div` elements to appear on the same line in the page then you need to set their styling rules. I'd suggest using `display: inline-block` or `float: left`, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: why does it matter how they are formatted as long as they are styled correctly?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I set those on `$('#append_div').append(`<div class="w-100"></div>`);`. Its not really making a difference

Comment: In which case please edit the question to include your code. We can't debug something we can't see

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I updated my code.

Comment: You've only set the styles on one of the divs. It needs to be on all of them, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/xo8ryc0j/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, still not working. What if I have my code inside `function myFunction(value, i) {` Does that interfere with anything?

Comment: No. This is purely a HTML/CSS issue

Comment: Ok, let me try some stuff. Thank you!